# Вычисление разницы в днях

Tags: php

Как вычислить кол-во дней от текущего момента до определенного момента следующего месяца.Попробовал вот так и возвращает почему то 0,месяц вообще не берет в счет какое бы там число не было.

```
function calcDifference($params){
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-07-11');
    $datetime2 = new DateTime('2016-08-11');
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%d');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте

```
echo $interval->format('%a');
```

Такая команда выведет полное кол-во целых суток в интервале. Команда в вашем вопросе выводит только число дней, не покрытых месяцем

Comment: То что надо,спасибо!